# Android Studio installs an APK for each module

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-gradle-plugin

I have an project, build with Gradle in Android Studio v 0.3.2.
My project has dependencies to two other modules(android library). The project structure is well defined with build.gradle files.
The problem is... when i run the project on an Android device, i get installed 3 apk's on my device. One is the main project(the only right one) and the other two are from the imported modules(theese two i don't want to get installed).
How can i achieve this? Or what i'm doing wrong?

Project Structure:

- **MyLibModule**
- **MainProject**
- MainProject->libraries->**MyOtherModule**

Where **MyLibModule** is at the same path as the Main project, because i also need this module in a other project.

Just to be clear: The whole project **build's OK**, all dependencies are OK, but why do i get 3 APK's on my device?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After a whole day struggling with this problem, i located the cause of this strange behaviour. The problem was the manifest of library module. Before i switched to Android studio i used Eclipse. And i had a testActivity declared in the manifest of the library project. Removing all test activities from the manifest's of my library modules solved the problem. Now Android Studio installs only the MainProject apk.

Some code:
The manifest of MyLibModule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.mylibmodule"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
    <application>
        <activity
            android:name=".TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Changed to:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     package="com.test.mylibmodule"
>     android:versionCode="1"
>     android:versionName="1.0" >
>
>     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
>     <application>
>     </application>
> </manifest>
> ```

....And the same for MyOtherModule.

NOTE: the empty **application** node must stay in the manifest, to avoid build errors.

Comment: Indeed, I had a library that had the application with a demo activity and it was creating two "versions" of the app.

Answer (score 11):

remove the intent-filter from your library's launch activity

```
<application>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Changed to

```
<application>
   <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
</application>
```

Comment: very good answer. am creating aar library using studio. after created aar lib file, importing to another project. while installed main apk file into mobile, its showing two apk in mobile screen.then. I followed your steps. I got perfect output.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your libraries are defined in their `build.gradle` files as being applications instead of libraries. Look for this line:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

and replace it with:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
```

You may need to make other adjustments to the buildfile as well because not everything that applies to applications can be specified in a library buildfile. See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-projects for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I hawe noticed that before and also read the documentation. But the problem was in the manifest of the libraries. I will post my solution as an answer soon.